# Aggregation of all possible unique combinations with observations in the same column in R

Tags: r, combinations, aggregation

I am trying to shorten a chunk of code to make it faster and easier to modify. This is a short example of my data.

```
   order obs year var1 var2 var3
1      3   1    1   32  588   NA
2      4   1    2   33  689 2385
3      5   1    3   NA  678 2369
4     33   3    1   10  214 1274
5     34   3    2   10  237 1345
6     35   3    3   10  242 1393
7     78   6    1    5   62   NA
8     79   6    2    5   75  296
9     80   6    3    5   76  500
10    93   7    1   NA   NA   NA
11    94   7    2    4   86  247
12    95   7    3    3   54  207
```

Basically, what I want is R to find any possible and unique combination of two values (observations) in column "obs", within the same year, to create a new matrix or DF with observations being the aggregation of the originals. Order is not important, so 1+6 = 6+1. For instance, having 150 observations, I will expect 11,175 feasible combinations (each year).

I sort of got what I want with basic coding but, as you will see, is way too long (I have built this way 66 different new data sets so it does not really make a sense) and I am wondering how to shorten it. I did some trials (plyr,...) with no real success. Here what I did:

```
# For the 1st year, groups of 2 obs
newmatrix <- data.frame(t(combn(unique(data$obs[data$year==1]), 2)))
colnames(newmatrix) <- c("obs1", "obs2")
newmatrix$name <- do.call(paste, c(newmatrix[c("obs1", "obs2")], sep = "_"))
# and the aggregation of var. using indexes, which I will skip here to save your time :)
```

To ilustrate, here the result, considering above sample, of what I would get for the 1st year. NA is because I only computed those where the 2 values were valid. And only for variables 1 and 3. More, I did the sum but it could be any other possible Function:

```
  order obs1 obs2 year var1 var3
1     1    1    3  1_3   42   NA
2     2    1    6  1_6   37   NA
3     3    1    7  1_7   NA   NA
4     4    3    6  3_6   15   NA
5     5    3    7  3_7   NA   NA
6     6    6    7  6_7   NA   NA
```

As for the 2 first lines in the 3rd year, same type of matrix:

```
  order obs1 obs2 year var1 var3
1     1    1    3  1_3   NA 3762
2     2    1    6  1_6   NA 2868
.......... etc ............
```

I hope I explained myself. Thank you in advance for your hints on how to do this more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use split-apply-combine to split by year, find all the combinations, and then combine back together:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(data, data$year), function(x) {
  p <- combn(nrow(x), 2)
  data.frame(order=paste(x$order[p[1,]], x$order[p[2,]], sep="_"),
             obs1=x$obs[p[1,]],
             obs2=x$obs[p[2,]],
             year=x$year[1],
             var1=x$var1[p[1,]] + x$var1[p[2,]],
             var2=x$var2[p[1,]] + x$var2[p[2,]],
             var3=x$var3[p[1,]] + x$var3[p[2,]])
}))
#     order obs1 obs2 year var1 var2 var3
# 1.1  3_33    1    3    1   42  802   NA
# 1.2  3_78    1    6    1   37  650   NA
# 1.3  3_93    1    7    1   NA   NA   NA
# 1.4 33_78    3    6    1   15  276   NA
# 1.5 33_93    3    7    1   NA   NA   NA
# 1.6 78_93    6    7    1   NA   NA   NA
# 2.1  4_34    1    3    2   43  926 3730
# 2.2  4_79    1    6    2   38  764 2681
# 2.3  4_94    1    7    2   37  775 2632
# 2.4 34_79    3    6    2   15  312 1641
# 2.5 34_94    3    7    2   14  323 1592
# 2.6 79_94    6    7    2    9  161  543
# 3.1  5_35    1    3    3   NA  920 3762
# 3.2  5_80    1    6    3   NA  754 2869
# 3.3  5_95    1    7    3   NA  732 2576
# 3.4 35_80    3    6    3   15  318 1893
# 3.5 35_95    3    7    3   13  296 1600
# 3.6 80_95    6    7    3    8  130  707
```

This enables you to be very flexible in how you combine data pairs of observations within a year --- `x[p[1,],]` represents the year-specific data for the first element in each pair and `x[p[2,],]` represents the year-specific data for the second element in each pair. You can return a year-specific data frame with any combination of data for the pairs, and the year-specific data frames are combined into a single final data frame with `do.call` and `rbind`.